# AngularFire2 Get Authenticated User ID in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm trying to work out how I can get the uid of the Firebase Authenticated user within TypeScipt:

```
<div> {{ (user | async)?.uid }} </div>
```

I have the following TS code:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-portal',
  templateUrl: './user-portal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-portal.component.css']
})
export class UserPortalComponent implements OnInit {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(
              public afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {
    this.user = afAuth.authState;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Everything I've read suggests I need to access the id property of...

```
this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid
```

... but this doesn't seem exposed. If I change that to...

```
this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.toJSON()
```

... and send that to the console, then indeed I see a uid property. How can I get that property?

Is this even the correct way to obtain a the uid for the user? Would...

```
this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken()
```

... be better? If this is better, I cannot see how to get the uid out of this either. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the uid from `idToken` `Observable`

```
this.afAuth.idToken.subscribe(user => {
            this.user = user;
            this.lists = this.af.list(`/lists/${user.uid}`);
        });
```

Keep in mind that this is an observable, meaning that you can create a chain using this as a base with `mergeMap`, `map`, etc.